# MVC4 method with Stream parameter cannot be invoked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, stream

I have the method with the signature indicated below:

```
   [OperationContract]
     public string UploadFile(Stream stream)
```

I don't seem to be able to invoke it, and I have no idea why!
Although I have other methods in the same controller but with parameters of type string, int, ..etc

Please note that This method is contained in a project that has been transferred from WCF (was functioning correctly) to Web API.
and this function should be called from an iOS code (i.e iPad)
and I have to use the same signature mentioned above.

So, is there any thing I'm missing or I should add something to make it recognizable?

Comment: WCF and Web Api are very different in some areas - this is one of them. How are you sending the streamed data over HTTP? Is it as a multipart stream?

Comment: The file I'm sending is an mp4 file, and it's being sent as a one part stream.